# Can't compute covariance matrix on a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following data set (which I import from a 6-column **Excel file** with a .csv file extension):

```
treas <- read.csv(file = 'treas.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

2YR     3YR     5YR     7YR     10YR    30YR
0.41    0.85    1.65    2.18    2.6     3.43
0.41    0.85    1.65    2.2     2.61    3.45
0.4     0.82    1.63    2.17    2.59    3.44
0.41    0.86    1.66    2.19    2.6     3.44
0.43    0.88    1.69    2.22    2.62    3.45
0.45    0.93    1.71    2.24    2.64    3.47
0.44    0.91    1.7     2.23    2.65    3.47
0.42    0.88    1.66    2.17    2.58    3.41
0.45    0.93    1.7     2.21    2.6     3.41
0.49    0.95    1.71    2.21    2.61    3.4
0.51    0.99    1.77    2.27    2.66    3.44
0.48    0.95    1.71    2.21    2.61    3.43
0.48    0.94    1.71    2.22    2.64    3.47
0.5     0.94    1.71    2.22    2.63    3.44
0.48    0.96    1.72    2.23    2.63    3.45
0.49    0.95    1.7     2.19    2.59    3.41
0.48    0.92    1.68    2.17    2.57    3.38
0.46    0.9     1.64    2.14    2.53    3.35
0.45    0.88    1.64    2.14    2.54    3.36
0.47    0.88    1.62    2.13    2.53    3.34
0.47    0.9     1.66    2.17    2.58    3.4
0.49    0.95    1.71    2.22    2.64    3.46
0.52    0.98    1.74    2.25    2.65    3.47
0.52    1       1.74    2.24    2.63    3.44
0.51    0.99    1.7     2.19    2.58    3.38
0.51    0.97    1.68    2.17    2.57    3.37
0.46    0.93    1.66    2.15    2.55    3.38
0.48    0.92    1.65    2.13    2.53    3.34
0.48    0.95    1.68    2.17    2.55    3.36
```

When I call the cov() method on the the `treas` data frame, I see the following error message:

```
Error: is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE
```

To check the data types, I use:

```
sapply(treas, typeof)
```

The result is:

```
        2YR         3YR         5YR         7YR        10YR        30YR 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

Calling `str(treas)` reveals:

```
str(treas)
'data.frame':   1252 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ 2YR  : Factor w/ 235 levels ".","0.34","0.35",..: 8 8 7 8 10 12 11 9 12 16 ...
 $ 3YR  : chr w/ 219 levels ".","0.66","0.69",..: 18 18 15 19 21 26 24 21 26 28 ...
 $ 5YR  : chr w/ 207 levels ".","0.94","0.95",..: 67 67 65 68 71 73 72 68 72 73 ...
 $ 7YR  : chr w/ 192 levels ".","1.19","1.20",..: 96 98 95 97 100 102 101 95 99 99 ...
 $ 10YR : chr w/ 178 levels ".","1.37","1.38",..: 118 119 117 118 120 122 123 116 118 119 ...
 $ 30YR : chr w/ 125 levels ".","2.11","2.14",..: 121 123 122 122 123 125 125 120 120 119 ...
```

I've tried to force the data frame to numeric using:

```
lapply(treas, as.numeric)
```

But, doing so results in:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In lapply(treas, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Then, I still get the same error when calling `cov(treas)`:

```
Error: is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE
```

Anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly here?  Thanks!

Comment: What does your dataframe look like after passing as.numeric to all the necessary columns? If it's all NAs, then you're doing something wrong there. If you have a mix of numbers and an occassional NA, then you probably just need to add na.rm = T to your cov function.

Comment: i think there is an issue with reading your files in. Processing the data afterwards is just a fix to an earlier made error. Try using the read.csv arguments. I had no issue while i copied your data and saved it in a csv. cov(treas) worked fine for me then

Comment: From `str` there appears to be at least 1 non-numeric value in each variable: a period symbol. That might be a clue as to where you're running into file import problems

Comment: Yes, there *is* a period in the data.  I removed that row from the source file and cov() works as expected.  Thank you!